# JSON file proper Case and word spacing

Tags: java, json

I am wondering what will be the best approach for word case and word delimiter in JSON

considering that later on the JSON file will be converted to a Java Pojo and i would like this Java Pojo to be in ProperCase

I am debating between:

```
"sectionSuspensionTiresSteering": [{
"SectionSuspensionTiresSteering": [{
"section_suspension_tires_steering": [{
"section Suspension Tires Steering": [{
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really think that JSON has a naming convention, so you can "choose" sort of speak. As I have a Java background, I prefer using camelCase (your first option). I would avoid using blank spaces in the JSON keys, it is allowed but causes problems because most of the existing framework aren't able to deal with it.

So you are free to use the style you want. Regarding the conversion back to Java Pojo, this is just a matter of annotations. When you use for example Jackson, it allows you to annotate your fields in order to convert the JSON file back to a Java Pojo.

Answer (score 1):

Use always the first one:

```
"sectionSuspensionTiresSteering": [{
```

Examples of similar files in official guides:
https://spring.io/guides/gs/authenticating-ldap/

As you can see here, the *gradle* file uses this notation and XMLs files too.

Answer (score 1):

I understand that *JSON* properties are written in camel case (`sectionSuspensionTiresSteering`) style.

But it has nothing to do with how the property will be written or coded in *java*.

For example if you use *Gson()* to do the conversions between *java* an *JSON* you can name the java property whatever you want and annotate the property with `@SerializedName("jsonName")` passing in the *JSON* property name.

What I mean is that the two names are not coupled.

Comment: Thanks Juan, your Json answer was edited by Jason :)